# Getting dimension parameters of Portrait mode only

Tags: android, landscape, dimensions

I am having an application running in **Portrait mode**. Now i want to open an intent in Full screen, **Landscape mode** and need to get the height and width of Landscape mode.

Below is the code.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);    
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
Display disp = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Log.i("Width: " + disp.getWidth() + ", Height: " + disp.getHeight());
```

All things are working fine, like screen getting open in Full Screen Mode, Landscape Mode is also working fine. But i am getting the height and width parameters of Portrait Mode only.

If i run the application in Landscape mode only then i am getting right height and width 
for same code.

How to solve this?

Comment: In manifest use, android:screenOrientation="landscape" for this particular activity. And we will get correct dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

That is because setRequestedOrientation will take time to effect. You can use your code to get the display in onRestart()/onResume.

> Change the desired orientation of this activity. If the activity is currently in the foreground or otherwise impacting the screen orientation, the screen will immediately be changed (possibly causing the activity to be restarted). Otherwise, this will be used the next time the activity is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach to get width and height of screen

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) activity.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
int height = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
int width = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
```

Comment: I think this is giving the whole phone width. But i just want the Display Screen width. I am having Samsung Galaxy S GT-9003 Phone. Having dimensions 480 * 800. Is there anyway to just get the Display Screen height and width?